# Get Value of nearest HTML thead element when clicking on td cell

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have an HTML table which looks like this:

```css
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#reservationtable tbody tr td').on('click', function () {
        var reservationtime = $( this ).siblings('th').text();
        var header = $(this).next('.theader-text-nonstrong').val();
        $('#modalvon').text(reservationtime);
        $('#modalbis').text(addMinutes(reservationtime, '60'));
        $('#modaldatum').text(header);
        $("#confirmreservierung").modal("show");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm res-table" id="reservationtable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="theader-text td-border-right"><svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-calendar" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V1h8V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V1h1a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h1V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM1 4v10a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h12a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4H1z"/></svg></th>
                <th scope="col" class="theader-text td-border-right" colspan="3"><?php echo "<span class='theader-text-nonstrong'>" . date("l") . "</span><br>" . date("d.m.Y"); ?></th>
                <th scope="col" class="theader-text td-border-right" colspan="3"><?php echo "<span class='theader-text-nonstrong'>" . date("l", strtotime("+1 day")). "</span><br>" . date("d.m.Y", strtotime("+1 day")); ?></th>
                <th scope="col" class="theader-text td-border-right" colspan="3"><?php echo "<span class='theader-text-nonstrong'>" . date("l", strtotime("+2 day")). "</span><br>" . date("d.m.Y", strtotime("+2 day")); ?></th>
                <th scope="col" class="theader-text td-border-right" colspan="3"><?php echo "<span class='theader-text-nonstrong'>" . date("l", strtotime("+3 day")). "</span><br>" . date("d.m.Y", strtotime("+3 day")); ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="td-border-right">Zeit</th>
                <th scope="col">Platz 1</th>
                <th scope="col">Platz 2</th>
                <th scope="col" class="td-border-right">Platz 3</th>
                <th scope="col">Platz 1</th>
                <th scope="col">Platz 2</th>
                <th scope="col" class="td-border-right">Platz 3</th>
                <th scope="col">Platz 1</th>
                <th scope="col">Platz 2</th>
                <th scope="col" class="td-border-right">Platz 3</th>
                <th scope="col">Platz 1</th>
                <th scope="col">Platz 2</th>
                <th scope="col" class="td-border-right">Platz 3</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" class="td-border-right">08:00</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" class="td-border-right">09:00</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" class="td-border-right">10:00</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" class="td-border-right">11:00</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" class="td-border-right">12:00</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" class="td-border-right">13:00</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" class="td-border-right">14:00</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" class="td-border-right">15:00</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" class="td-border-right">16:00</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" class="td-border-right">17:00</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" class="td-border-right">18:00</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" class="td-border-right">19:00</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row" class="td-border-right">20:00</th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="td-border-right"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Also, I have a jquery method which handles the event when a user clicks on a td in the table:

As you can see I want to load data inside the bootstrap modal. I want to get the value from the column header of the td which was clicked. Especially I want to get the value out of the span with the 'theater-text-nonstrong' class. The current method only gets me a null value.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: No, because the solutions don't work in my program

Comment: @freedomn-m this retrieves [object Object] inside of the modal

Comment: @freedomn-m can you please show me how it might work in a short example? I'm not very good in jquery.

Comment: @freedomn-m okay this solution gets me the day but the problem is that it is working on only on some cells, and also it must not get the value from the "correct" column where the td is

Comment: My bad, didn't notice the colspans in that huge amount of html provided

Comment: sorry for adding so much html, should have shortened the table

Comment: It's fine - probably didn't need so many rows, but it's enough to show the issue, which is the important part.

Comment: @freedomn-m what would i have to do different if i want to retrieve in which column of "Platz 1", "Platz 2" or "Platz 3" is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have colspans involved one way is create an array for all the headings text.
On page load go through all the `<th colspan>` and get the colspan value and use that value to push text into the headings array for each column spanned.

Then when you click a `<td>` use it's index within cells on that row to get the associated heading text from the headings array

```js
// add some cell text for demo
demoInit();

let spanHeadings = [];

$('thead th[colspan]').each(function() {
  const colspan = +this.colSpan,
    heading = $(this).find('.theader-text-nonstrong').text();
  // create as many headings as colspan length
  spanHeadings.push.apply(spanHeadings, Array(colspan).fill(heading));
});


$('#reservationtable tbody td').click(function() {
  const tdIdx = $(this).index() - 1;// subtract for the left `<th>`
  const heading = spanHeadings[tdIdx];
  console.clear()
  console.log('heading: ', heading)
});

function demoInit() {
  $('td:empty').text(function(i) {
    return 'Cell ' + (i + 1)
  });

}
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 4px
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm res-table" id="reservationtable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" class="theader-text td-border-right"><svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-calendar" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M3.5 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V1h8V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V1h1a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h1V.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5zM1 4v10a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h12a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V4H1z"/></svg></th>
      <th scope="col" class="theader-text td-border-right" colspan="3"><span class='theader-text-nonstrong'>Span 1</span></th>
      <th scope="col" class="theader-text td-border-right" colspan="3"><span class='theader-text-nonstrong'>Span 2</span><br></th>
      <th scope="col" class="theader-text td-border-right" colspan="3"><span class='theader-text-nonstrong'>Span 3</span><br></th>
      <th scope="col" class="theader-text td-border-right" colspan="3"><span class='theader-text-nonstrong'>Span 4</span></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" class="td-border-right">Zeit</th>
      <th scope="col">Platz 1</th>
      <th scope="col">Platz 2</th>
      <th scope="col" class="td-border-right">Platz 3</th>
      <th scope="col">Platz 1</th>
      <th scope="col">Platz 2</th>
      <th scope="col" class="td-border-right">Platz 3</th>
      <th scope="col">Platz 1</th>
      <th scope="col">Platz 2</th>
      <th scope="col" class="td-border-right">Platz 3</th>
      <th scope="col">Platz 1</th>
      <th scope="col">Platz 2</th>
      <th scope="col" class="td-border-right">Platz 3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" class="td-border-right">08:00</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="td-border-right"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="td-border-right"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="td-border-right"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="td-border-right"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" class="td-border-right">09:00</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="td-border-right"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="td-border-right"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="td-border-right"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="td-border-right"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```